# Avahi zeroconf mDNS on 22.04 is not appending .local to host names as it should

Tags: networking, printing

I upgraded a machine to 22.04 and found that the mDNS name and the avahi-discover names are different.

The command `host mylaptop` give me `mylaptop.xxx.comcast.net` while avahi-discover gives me `mylaptop.local`.  I have another 20.04 installation that gives `mylaptop.local` both ways.  E.g. I can log to another local server using the command `ssh server` but not `ssh server.local`.

These name changes would be okay, but the lack of consistency breaks my Cups printing since avahi tells cups that the name is `server.local` not `server`.

Any thoughts what needs to be changed or fixed?   I tried a reinstall of libnss-mdns thinking some config from 20.04 might have been preserved, but that made no difference.